# Can we create a global variable whose value can be accessed in any where in the application?

Tags: c#, class-library

I have a class library project, I want to create a variable and assign a value to it through `MethodA()` whose value can be access through `MethodB()`.
Just like we have a session in `ASP.NET`.

I cannot pass as a parameter to `MethodB()` because `MethodB()` is being used in many places and if I change it,  all the other methods will get affected.

```
Public Void MethodA()
{
string value ="Hello";
}

public Void MethodB()
{
-- I want to read the value which is set in MethodA()
}
```

I need to dispose the value as well after reading it in `MethodB()`.

Both of these methods are in different classes inside the same project.

Comment: if `MethodA` and `MethodB` are in the same class, don't make the variable scoped to the method, but use private field

Comment: sorry forgot to mention, they are different classes inside same project

Comment: Make in `internal`, then. If you really want it to be available anywhere (even outside of the assembly), make it `public`

Comment: Read about variable-scopes, e.g. here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-of-variables-in-c-sharp/

Answer (score 0):

First try to create a property with a private setter:

```
public class A
{
    public string Value { get { return MethodA();  } }

    public string MethodA()
    {
        return "Hello";
    }

    public void MethodB()
    {
        var value = Value;
    }
}
```

If you have two classes:

```
public class A
{
    public string FooMethod()
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
}


public class B
{
    public string BarMethod()
    {
        var result = new A().FooMethod();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this approach (and global variables more generally) is that `MethodB` might now use `Value` before it was initialised. Ideally the getter of `Value` should call `MethodA` the first time it is called. Better yet would be to generally avoid a global access pattern and use parameters instead.

Comment: Or set it in the constructor

Comment: You might be able to use a static property. This will be global and have the same value Even you create multiple objects.

Comment: @zach  my value will keep changing

Comment: If you want to get it without A class object, it should be static

Answer (score 0):

You can get idea to handle your exception

```
 public class test
{
    public static int value = 0; //Global variable
    public void MethodA()
    {
    //you can assign here as well
        value++;
    }
}

  public class HomeController : Controller
{
    test t = new test();
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
         t.MethodA();
        int d = test.value;
        //you can assign here as well
        test.value = 100;
        int dd = test.value;
        return View();
    }
   }
```